# In the Terminal is there a way to search for a command you previously entered?

Tags: linux, mac, unix, terminal

In the Terminal is there a way to search for a command you previously entered?  Say you typed something in just a moment ago, you can press the up arrow.  But if you typed it in hours ago, or a day ago, is there a way to search for keywords that existed in this command, then to retrieve the command?